# How to add a role on when a new member joins?

Tags: discord.js

I want to automatically assign a role to every user that joins a guild. I'm using the code below: it doesn't work, but it logs no error.
I've already checked that my bot has the permission to manage roles.

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {      
  var role = member.guild.roles.find('Member', 'user');
  member.addRole(role);
});
```

Comment: Can you show the content of role? `console.log(role)`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're using `roles.find()` in a wrong way: if you want the role's `.name` to be `'Members'`, you should write:

```js
var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'Member');
member.addRole(role);
```

This should work, but it's a deprecated way to do that:  it means that discord.js's developers are going to remove it in the future. To avoid having to change that later, you can already start using the non-deprecated way: you should pass a function that returns whether a role matches your criteria. This is better because you can combine multiple properties and checks.

```js
var role = member.guild.find((role) => { // long way
  if (role.name == 'Member') return true;
});

var role = member.guild.find(role => role.name == 'Member'); // shorter way
```